# Lime samples won't compile

Tags: haxe, openfl, lime-haxe

I can't build lime samples. What am I missing? What's going on?

This is what I've been doing for the last few days:

- Download and install latest version of haxe
- haxelib install lime
- haxelib run lime setup
- haxelib run lime create SimpleImage C:/ex
- haxelib run lime test C:/ex flash

And I get this:

```
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/lime/2,9,0/lime/graphics/format/BMP.hx:60: characters 3-16 : haxe.io.Bytes has no field setInt32
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/lime/2,9,0/lime/graphics/format/BMP.hx:61: characters 3-17 : haxe.io.Bytes has no field setUInt16
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/lime/2,9,0/lime/graphics/format/BMP.hx:62: characters 3-17 : haxe.io.Bytes has no field setUInt16
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/lime/2,9,0/lime/graphics/format/BMP.hx:63: characters 3-16 : haxe.io.Bytes has no field setInt32
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/lime/2,9,0/lime/graphics/format/BMP.hx:67: characters 2-15 : haxe.io.Bytes has no field setInt32
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/lime/2,9,0/lime/graphics/format/BMP.hx:68: characters 2-15 : haxe.io.Bytes has no field setInt32
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/lime/2,9,0/lime/graphics/format/BMP.hx:69: characters 2-15 : haxe.io.Bytes has no field setInt32
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/lime/2,9,0/lime/graphics/format/BMP.hx:70: characters 2-16 : haxe.io.Bytes has no field setUInt16
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/lime/2,9,0/lime/graphics/format/BMP.hx:71: characters 2-16 : haxe.io.Bytes has no field setUInt16
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/lime/2,9,0/lime/graphics/format/BMP.hx:72: characters 2-15 : haxe.io.Bytes has no field setInt32
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/lime/2,9,0/lime/graphics/format/BMP.hx:73: characters 2-15 : haxe.io.Bytes has no field setInt32
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/lime/2,9,0/lime/graphics/format/BMP.hx:74: characters 2-15 : haxe.io.Bytes has no field setInt32
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/lime/2,9,0/lime/graphics/format/BMP.hx:75: characters 2-15 : haxe.io.Bytes has no field setInt32
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/lime/2,9,0/lime/graphics/format/BMP.hx:76: characters 2-15 : haxe.io.Bytes has no field setInt32
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/lime/2,9,0/lime/graphics/format/BMP.hx:77: characters 2-15 : haxe.io.Bytes has no field setInt32
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/lime/2,9,0/lime/graphics/format/BMP.hx:81: characters 3-16 : haxe.io.Bytes has no field setInt32
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/lime/2,9,0/lime/graphics/format/BMP.hx:82: characters 3-16 : haxe.io.Bytes has no field setInt32
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/lime/2,9,0/lime/graphics/format/BMP.hx:83: characters 3-16 : haxe.io.Bytes has no field setInt32
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/lime/2,9,0/lime/graphics/format/BMP.hx:84: characters 3-16 : haxe.io.Bytes has no field setInt32
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/lime/2,9,0/lime/graphics/utils/ImageDataUtil.hx:1088: characters 14-24 : Unknown identifier : NOT_EQUALS
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/lime/2,9,0/lime/graphics/utils/ImageDataUtil.hx:1089: characters 14-20 : Unknown identifier : EQUALS
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/lime/2,9,0/lime/graphics/utils/ImageDataUtil.hx:1090: characters 14-23 : Unknown identifier : LESS_THAN
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/lime/2,9,0/lime/graphics/utils/ImageDataUtil.hx:1091: characters 14-35 : Unknown identifier : LESS_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/lime/2,9,0/lime/graphics/utils/ImageDataUtil.hx:1092: characters 14-26 : Unknown identifier : GREATER_THAN
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/lime/2,9,0/lime/graphics/utils/ImageDataUtil.hx:1093: characters 14-38 : Unknown identifier : GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/lime/2,9,0/lime/graphics/utils/ImageDataUtil.hx:1137: characters 11-21 : Capture variables must be lower-case
```

I get all kind of errors when I try to compile other projects. All those errors are as weird as these, as if haxe didn't know it's own classes.

Thank you very much for your time!

PS: haxelib list:

```
hxcpp: [3.2.205]
lime-samples: [2.6.0]
lime: [2.9.0]
```

Comment: sanity check: type "haxe" in the cmd line, what version does it report?

Comment: @larsiusprime It says it's 3.1.3

Comment: That might be your issue; 3.1.3 is not the latest version of haxe, the latest version is 3.2.1:
http://haxe.org/download/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as [@larsiusprime](https://stackoverflow.com/users/486704/larsiusprime) guessed in comment to question, it looks like wrong haxe version

yours haxe version is 3.1.3

meanwhile latest haxe version 3.2.1

try to update haxe toolkit